# How do I get ASP.NET Web API to return JSON instead of XML using Chrome?

Tags: json, google-chrome, asp.net-web-api

Using the newer **ASP.NET Web API**, in **Chrome** I am seeing XML - how can I change it to request **JSON** so I can view it in the browser? I do believe it is just part of the request headers, am I correct in that?

Comment: There is a discussion here to make returning JSON only the default behavior: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/1765

Answer (score 1832, accepted):

##### Note: Read the comments of this answer, it can produce a XSS Vulnerability if you are using the default error handing of WebAPI

I just add the following in `App_Start / WebApiConfig.cs` class in my MVC **Web API** project.

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes
    .Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html") );
```

That makes sure you get JSON on most queries, but you can get `XML` when you send `text/xml`.

If you need to have the response `Content-Type` as `application/json` please check [Todd's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20556625/287145).

`NameSpace` is using `System.Net.Http.Headers`.

Comment: This is a surprisingly overlooked answer, and although the original question wasn't totally clear, this directly makes JSON the default response for a web browser (which sends Accept: text/html). Good job.

Comment: I like this much better than requiring a json=true query parameter.

Comment: +1 Far and away the best answer. I imagine there are a ton of ppl who opt to completely remove XML just because they don't see JSON in the browser.

Comment: Well done. [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20556625/62600) expands on this a bit by accepting text/html but returning application/json, in case you happen to use a Chrome extension that expects it for formatting.

Comment: @Felipe: Did you add your line above into the Global.asax?
Do you mean: `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));`?

Comment: I haven't worked with WebAPI for a while but i'm pretty sure that's it.

Comment: I found when I did this that data provided by a third party with HTML break tags in it ended up with carriage returns. The JSON was then invalid. Better to use the accepted answer if this affects you.

Comment: Note that the response's `Content-Type` header will still be `text/html`.

Comment: why text/html? Isn't the type for json: application/json ? When I used the solution above and put application/json instead of text/html, I got the response in XML. Isn't this counter intuitive? application/json should have worked. What is the reasoning for this?

Comment: This is horrible. The response content type header should be application/json. This "solution" makes it text/html.

Comment: This was the solution to display on chrome. While not perfect it fits, in case you need the Content-Type as application/json you can check Todd's answer.

Comment: Note that if the _request_ "Accept" header field is "application/json" (ie set in an ajax GET request), it should return json back. Mine does this but displays xml if you open the url in chrome (where request accept is not set to json).

Comment: In my case not configuration was needed json serialization was in place by default. Based on the content negotiation rules if there is not agreement the content will be converted into json.

Comment: In case you want to lock down to json only, I suggest you clear all formaters and enable Json only.
`GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();`
`GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());`

Comment: I'm annoyed that Stack Overflow doesn't allow me to take back my upvote because this is not what I'm looking for. Cameln, probably because people jump the gun thinking this solution is correct. Why is MS not setting this up properly with JSON by default? I've done this through a Certified Microsoft class and will I'll try to locate the proper solution.

Comment: Why/How would JSON support HTML?

Comment: Only 40 people noticed that there's a way better answer. (via @meffect just remap the response type instead of setting the wrong default.)

Comment: This is a stupid hack, not a good answer. Why would one modify their code for something so simple as setting a request header? If you are so keen on writing code for this rather recommend writing tests. And I guess naspinski and others realized that they can't test POST, PUT, DELETE etc with a plain browser.

Comment: This answer could potentially expose an XSS vulnerability. WebAPI will include the full URL on a 404 response, and because the content type is text/html, the browser will happily execute any JavaScript included in the query string.

Comment: For detailed configuration, one can look at reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization

Comment: I agree with @meffect, this is a "fine" answer for a development environment, but if you use this solution in a production setting you will open yourself up to XSS attacks.

Comment: Why are so many MS-using devs okay with hacky answers? Your web client would be receiving responses inconsistent with the requested format. When you request text/html you should be receiving HTML. When you request application/json you should be getting back JSON. Sheeesh.

Comment: Like others have pointed out, this causes an XSS vulnerability on the web api 404 page since the URL that causes the 404 is included as content on the 404 error page. DO NOT USE.

Answer (score 523):

If you do this in the `WebApiConfig` you will get JSON by default, but it will still allow you to return XML if you pass `text/xml` as the request `Accept` header.

#### Note: This removes the support for `application/xml`

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
    }
}
```

If you are not using the MVC project type and therefore did not have this class to begin with, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990036/how-to-add-web-api-to-an-existing-asp-net-mvc-4-web-application-project) for details on how to incorporate it.

Comment: Just to note, the original behaviour is correct. Chrome requests `application/xml` with a priority of 0.9 and `*/*` with a priority of 0.8. By removing `application/xml` you remove the ability for the Web API to return XML if the client requests that specifically. e.g. if you send "Accept: application/xml" you will *still* receive JSON.

Comment: Based on @Porges's comment, I suggest wrapping the two lines that remove XML support in a #if DEBUG directive. This way in dev you can use Chrome's address bar to test your api and get json by defaut and you will still offer support XML in your prod environment.

Comment: Is it me, or is the first sentence incorrect? The code appears to totally remove XML, not simply change the default.

Comment: @NickG: yes and no, it removes application/xml support but you can still use text/xml. (Although text/xml is considered deprecated)

Comment: @NickG: a solution that is overlooked here and IMHO is a much better option (keeping application/xml) is the solution proposed by Felipe Leusin lower on this page. Using config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));

Comment: So, how do we do it via web config so we get json by default and XML if requested?

Comment: @Felipse Leusin's answer below is actually shorter and works better.

Answer (score 352):

Using RequestHeaderMapping works even better, because it also sets the `Content-Type = application/json` in the response header, which allows Firefox (with JSONView add-on) to format the response as JSON.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings
.Add(new System.Net.Http.Formatting.RequestHeaderMapping("Accept", 
                              "text/html",
                              StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase,
                              true, 
                              "application/json"));
```

Comment: This is the most lean and simplest solution and Fiddler also detects the content type being returned as josn.

Comment: Nice! Where would you suggest putting this in the code?

Comment: It should go in WebApiConfig.cs

Comment: Also a great fix for the jsonformatter extension which breaks without this.

Comment: for some reason though the jsonp formatter extension breaks though when doing this... https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp

Comment: Worked for me. I needed to add a **using System.Net.Http.Formatting;**

Comment: Linking for my own convenience: This answer plays nicely with another setup step I usually perform: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28337589/398630.

Comment: And to be clear, this just changes the default. You can always get either JSON or XML simply by including the relevant "Accept" header.

Comment: It works great for JSON but it does not return properly formatted XML.

Comment: This works great with the newest version of browsers when using the .NET Framework still.

Comment: Works great ! You could add the code below to return indented JSON :
        `var jsonFormat = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
        jsonFormat.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;` (need to add using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;)

Answer (score 329):

I like [Felipe Leusin's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13277616/62600) best - make sure browsers get JSON without compromising content negotiation from clients that actually want XML. The only missing piece for me was that the response headers still contained content-type: text/html. Why was that a problem? Because I use the [JSON Formatter Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa), which inspects content-type, and I don't get the pretty formatting I'm used to. I fixed that with a simple custom formatter that accepts text/html requests and returns application/json responses:

```
public class BrowserJsonFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
    public BrowserJsonFormatter() {
        this.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
        this.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    }

    public override void SetDefaultContentHeaders(Type type, HttpContentHeaders headers, MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType) {
        base.SetDefaultContentHeaders(type, headers, mediaType);
        headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    }
}
```

Register like so:

```
config.Formatters.Add(new BrowserJsonFormatter());
```

Comment: In the constructor add `this.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;` if you want it pretty-printed without a browser extension.

Comment: Perfect.  I was having issues with Felipe's solution returning a Content-Type of `text/html` and this fixed it (and made the response correct!)  I combined your answer with suhair's answer so that I get JSON sent to the browser by default but have the option of adding "format=xml" or "format=json" to the querystring to select a specific formatter. Thanks!

Comment: why would you want it to pretty print over the wire?

Comment: @meffect pretty-printing is preferred when viewing in a browser. Clients requesting json via application/json would still have non indented json returned.

Comment: Isn't @dmit77 's [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26068063/532517) better (more concise) than this one?

Comment: @AlastairMaw good idea, added your suggestion so pretty-printing works without the browser extension.

Comment: @eddiegroves you dont want pretty-print over the wire. You want the server to send the least amount of bits over the wire (ie: no spaces). Then you want the browser to format it nicely, with addons and such. Javascript needs to parse the JSON usually, why make it slower by introducing unnecessary formatting

Comment: Thanks Todd, best answer: 1) Correct return type, 2) keeps pretty formatting ONLY from a browser AND 3) I don't have to add a new accept type to Firefox and Chrome works also!  Sweetness.

Comment: For the googlers who are looking for: don't forget to add `using System.Net.Http.Formatting` and `using Newtonsoft.Json`

Comment: To make sure international characters are returned correcty, set the correct charset by adding the line `headers.ContentType.CharSet = "utf-8";` to the bottom of `SetDefaultContentHeaders()` function.

Comment: The solution doesn't work with IE (e.g. still asking to download json file). Any fix for this ?

Answer (score 192):

MVC4 Quick Tip #3–Removing the XML Formatter from ASP.Net Web API

In `Global.asax` add the line:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
```

like so:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    BundleTable.Bundles.RegisterTemplateBundles();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Works - much nicer having JSON be the default instead of XML.

Comment: but can you still return xml then?

Comment: I tested it, and you can't. So this is removing XML support.. Ye be warned, dear google people

Comment: If you have a look at my answer below, this will let xml still be returned if you want to but lets the site respond with JSON to the browser

Comment: @GlennSlaven yeah your answer should be the one marked as the correct one.

Comment: Adding only last line `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();` worked for me. I was getting error in all other lines. It is `Web Form Apllication`

Answer (score 121):

In the **WebApiConfig.cs**, add to the end of the **Register** function:

```
// Remove the XML formatter
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

[Source](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization).

Comment: Is XmlFormatter new in MVC4?

Comment: In MVC5, this can be done by replacing config with GlobalConfiguration.Configuration

Comment: For a project that must support JSON only and under no circumstance can be allowed to emit XML this is by far the best option.

Comment: config.Formatters.Add(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter);

Comment: That's terrible. -- This will always return JSON no matter what, even if the client specifically asks for XML in the Content-Type header.

Comment: Projects that do not test the XML version of the API as thoroughly as their JSON version should opt for this. Objects are serialized differently by the different formatters as per the link that Michael included. For example: XML formatters do not serialize read-only fields, while the JSON formatter does.

Answer (score 101):

In the **Global.asax** I am using the code below. My URI to get JSON is `http://www.digantakumar.com/api/values?json=true`

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(new  QueryStringMapping("json", "true", "application/json"));
}
```

Comment: Great one. What is your method expect a parameter? like http://localhost:61044/api/values/getdate?json=true,date=2012-08-01

Answer (score 54):

Have a look at content negotiation in the WebAPI. These ([Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kiranchalla/archive/2012/02/25/content-negotiation-in-asp-net-mvc4-web-api-beta-part-1.aspx) & [Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kiranchalla/archive/2012/02/27/content-negotiation-in-asp-net-mvc4-web-api-beta-part-2.aspx)) wonderfully detailed and thorough blog posts explain how it works.

In short, you are right, and just need to set the `Accept` or `Content-Type` request headers. Given your Action isn't coded to return a specific format, you can set `Accept: application/json`.

Comment: "so I can view it in the browser"

Comment: @Spongman, yes you can. But use an extension like REST Client - most browsers have one like it. The direct typing of url in a browser is 1. Too limiting (no control over headers, cannot post data and etc); 2. Incorrect - The browser does not consume the web api as it is intended to be consumed - you cannot rely on it testing it properly. So, again, a good REST client add-on would fix that.

Answer (score 45):

As the question is Chrome-specific, you can get the [Postman extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en-US&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher) which allows you to set the request content type.

[image: Postman]

Comment: In Firefox, simply go to about:config, search for accept.default and change the content of the `network.http.accept.default` configuration to `text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/json;q=0.9,application/xml;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.7`.

Comment: Or better yet, just `text/html,application/xhtml+xml;q=1.0,*/*;q=0.7` to avoid buggy hosts such as Bitbucket from accidentally serving your browser JSON in lieu of HTML.

Comment: The URL is dead.  A new one is https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en.

Answer (score 37):

This code makes json my default and allows me to use the XML format as well. I'll just append the `xml=true`.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(new QueryStringMapping("xml", "true", "application/xml"));
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: This is the most flexible answer (and really should be the default configuration these days). To add to this answer, JSON is the default, including from browser.  To view XML, add query string: ?xml=true

Comment: Tried a number of strategies.  Had a simple test for both XML and JSON and this worked out of the box

Answer (score 35):

One quick option is to use the MediaTypeMapping specialization. Here is an example of using  QueryStringMapping in the Application_Start event:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(new QueryStringMapping("a", "b", "application/json"));
```

Now whenever the url contains the querystring ?a=b in this case, Json response will be shown in the browser.

Comment: This was very useful.  You can also use UriPathExtensionMapping instead of QueryStringMapping if you want to use path.to/item.json

Answer (score 22):

Don't use your browser to test your API.

Instead, try to use an HTTP client that allows you to specify your request, such as CURL, or even Fiddler.

The problem with this issue is in the client, not in the API. The web API behaves correctly, according to the browser's request.

Comment: Why not use the browser? It is an obvious tool for it.

Comment: I think the point here is correct and important - we should not overfix a working part of the application (the MVC WebAPI infrastructure) if the problem is caused by the client. The real use case for an Api is to be properly used (by supplying correct headers), which is responsibility of the application. I disagree with completely discarding the browser though - for testing, there are plenty of tools for almost any browser (Rest Client-like extensions to start with).

Comment: This should probably be a comment.

Answer (score 20):

Most of the above answers makes perfect sense.
Since you are seeing data being formatted in XML format ,that means XML formatter is applied,SO you can see JSON format just by removing the XMLFormatter from the HttpConfiguration parameter like

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );                
            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);                
            config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
        }
```

since JSON is the default format

Answer (score 15):

Returning the correct format is done by the media-type formatter.
As others mentioned, you can do this in the `WebApiConfig` class:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ...

        // Configure Web API to return JSON
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter
        .SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));

        ...
    }
}
```

For more, check:

- [Media Formatters in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters).
- [Content Negotiation in ASP.NET Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation).

In case your actions are returning XML (which is the case by default) and you need just a specific method to return JSON, you can then use an `ActionFilterAttribute` and apply it to that specific action.

**Filter attribute:**

```
public class JsonOutputAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        ObjectContent content = actionExecutedContext.Response.Content as ObjectContent;
        var value = content.Value;
        Type targetType = actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];

        var httpResponseMsg = new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            RequestMessage = actionExecutedContext.Request,
            Content = new ObjectContent(targetType, value, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter(), (string)null)
        };

        actionExecutedContext.Response = httpResponseMsg;
        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```

**Applying to action:**

```
[JsonOutput]
public IEnumerable<Person> GetPersons()
{
    return _repository.AllPersons(); // the returned output will be in JSON
}
```

Note that you can omit the word `Attribute` on the action decoration and use just `[JsonOutput]` instead of `[JsonOutputAttribute]`.

Comment: Perfect explanations

Answer (score 14):

In the latest version of ASP.net WebApi 2, under `WebApiConfig.cs`, this will work:

```
config.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
config.Formatters.Add(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
```

Answer (score 11):

I used a global action filter to remove `Accept: application/xml` when the `User-Agent` header contains "Chrome":

```
internal class RemoveXmlForGoogleChromeFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public bool AllowMultiple
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteActionFilterAsync(
        HttpActionContext actionContext,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken,
        Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
    {
        var userAgent = actionContext.Request.Headers.UserAgent.ToString();
        if (userAgent.Contains("Chrome"))
        {
            var acceptHeaders = actionContext.Request.Headers.Accept;
            var header =
                acceptHeaders.SingleOrDefault(
                    x => x.MediaType.Contains("application/xml"));
            acceptHeaders.Remove(header);
        }

        return await continuation();
    }
}
```

Seems to work.

Answer (score 10):

I found the Chrome app "Advanced REST Client" excellent to work with REST services.  You can set the Content-Type to `application/json` among other things: 
[Advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo)

Answer (score 10):

```cs
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 7):

It's unclear to me why there is all of this complexity in the answer.  Sure there are lots of ways you can do this, with QueryStrings, headers and options... but what I believe to be the best practice is simple.  You request a plain URL (ex: `http://yourstartup.com/api/cars`) and in return you get JSON. You get JSON with the proper response header:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

In looking for an answer to this very same question, I found this thread, and had to keep going because this accepted answer doesn't work exactly.  I did find an answer which I feel is just too simple not to be the best one:

[Set the default WebAPI formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730951/set-the-default-webapi-formatter)

I'll add my tip here as well.

```
WebApiConfig.cs

namespace com.yourstartup
{
  using ...;
  using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
  ...
  config.Formatters.Clear(); //because there are defaults of XML..
  config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
}
```

I do have a question of where the defaults (at least the ones I am seeing) come from.  Are they .NET defaults, or perhaps created somewhere else (by someone else on my project).  Anways, hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

You can use as below:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Comment: If you're making a WebAPI app for just passing JSON messages, consider this answer.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution similar to [jayson.centeno's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18582910/458354) and other answers, but using the built-in extension from `System.Net.Http.Formatting`.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // add support for the 'format' query param
    // cref: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hongyes/archive/2012/09/02/support-format-in-asp-net-web-api.aspx
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.AddQueryStringMapping("$format", "json", "application/json");
    config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.AddQueryStringMapping("$format", "xml", "application/xml");

    // ... additional configuration
 }
```

The solution was primarily geared toward supporting $format for OData in the early releases of WebApi, but it also applies to the non-OData implementation, and returns the 
`Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8` header in the response.

It allows you to tack `&$format=json` or `&$format=xml` to the end of your uri when testing with a browser. It does not interfere with other expected behavior when using a non-browser client where you can set your own headers.

Answer (score 6):

Just add those two line of code on your **WebApiConfig** class

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
     public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
     {
          //add this two line 
          config.Formatters.Clear();
          config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());


          ............................
      }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You just change the `App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs` like this:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        //Below formatter is used for returning the Json result.
        var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
        //Default route
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "ApiControllerOnly",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
       );
    }
```

Comment: Removing a formatter is generally not a good idea, you are removing functionality.

Comment: Actually in this case, it works well for me, also many others suggest a way like this. I've learned it from http://myview.rahulnivi.net/building-spa-angular-mvc-5/  book!

Answer (score 3):

Some time has passed since this question was asked (and answered) but another option is to override the Accept header on the server during request processing using a MessageHandler as below:

```
public class ForceableContentTypeDelegationHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
                HttpRequestMessage request,
                CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var someOtherCondition = false;
        var accHeader = request.Headers.GetValues("Accept").FirstOrDefault();
        if (someOtherCondition && accHeader.Contains("application/xml"))
        {
            request.Headers.Remove("Accept");
            request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        }
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Where `someOtherCondition` can be anything including browser type, etc. This would be for conditional cases where only sometimes do we want to override the default content negotiation. Otherwise as per other answers, you would simply remove an unnecessary formatter from the configuration.

You'll need to register it of course. You can either do this globally:

```
  public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
      config.MessageHandlers.Add(new ForceableContentTypeDelegationHandler());
  }
```

or on a route by route basis:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "SpecialContentRoute",
   routeTemplate: "api/someUrlThatNeedsSpecialTreatment/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "SpecialTreatment" id = RouteParameter.Optional },
   constraints: null,
   handler: new ForceableContentTypeDelegationHandler()
);
```

And since this is a message handler it will run on both the request and response ends of the pipeline much like an `HttpModule`. So you could easily acknowledge the override with a custom header:

```
public class ForceableContentTypeDelegationHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
                HttpRequestMessage request,
                CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var wasForced = false;
        var someOtherCondition = false;
        var accHeader = request.Headers.GetValues("Accept").FirstOrDefault();
        if (someOtherCondition && accHeader.Contains("application/xml"))
        {
            request.Headers.Remove("Accept");
            request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            wasForced = true;
        }

        var response =  await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        if (wasForced){
          response.Headers.Add("X-ForcedContent", "We overrode your content prefs, sorry");
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the easiest way that I have used in my applications. Add given below 3 lines of code in `App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs` in the `Register` function:

```cs
var formatters = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters;

formatters.Remove(formatters.XmlFormatter);

config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

Asp.net web API will automatically serialize your returning object to JSON and as the `application/json` is added in the header so the browser or the receiver will understand that you are returning JSON result.

Answer (score 2):

From **MSDN** [Building a Single Page Application with ASP.NET and AngularJS](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/3-644) (about 41 mins in).

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // ... possible routing etc.

        // Setup to return json and camelcase it!
        var formatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        formatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
            new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    }
```

It should be current, I tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

WebApiConfig is the place where you can configure whether you want to output in json or xml. By default, it is xml. In the register function, we can use HttpConfiguration Formatters to format the output.

`System.Net.Http.Headers => MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html")` is required to get the output in the json format.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using **Felipe Leusin**'s answer for years, after a recent update of core libraries and of Json.Net, I ran into a `System.MissingMethodException`:SupportedMediaTypes.
The solution in my case, hopefully helpful to others experiencing the same unexpected exception, is to install `System.Net.Http`. NuGet apparently removes it in some circumstances. After a manual installation, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score -3):

I'm astonished to see so many replies requiring coding to change a single use case (GET) in *one* API instead of using a proper tool what has to be installed once and can be used for *any* API (own or 3rd party) and all use cases.

So the good answer is:

1. If you only want to request json or other content type install [Requestly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-redirect-url-mo/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa) or a similar tool and modify the Accept header.
2. If you want to use POST too and have nicely formatted json, xml, etc. use a proper API testing extension like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) or [ARC](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo).

Comment: Some prefer doing things without adding bloat in the form of extra tools and libraries.

Comment: It is still wrong to make changes to the API only because someone is using the wrong tool for the job. A web browser is not designed to test APIs, not even to view the output of APIs but to view documents. It is even worse if someone thinks an API tester tool is bloat instead of part of mandatory toolkit for any API developer, and honestly I would add front end developers too because they need to interact and experiment with APIs as well. It's also probably not enough because the browser without addins doesn't allow to set headers, post to an API or even inspect response headers.

Comment: I understand what you're saying and you're not wrong. But just off-topic, the reason why you are getting down-voted is the tone in which you answer the question. You sound very combative and come across as that developer that think they know everything, and that's very distasteful. I'm certain you are a great developer, judging by your responses. But, you must learn, especially in a professional QA environment like this, to address and convince people in a friendlier and more human way. Perhaps, first give the answer they want, then explain a better way, and motivate why it's better.