# Using Microsoft.Extension.DependencyInjection in Asp.net Web Api2

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to implement Asp.Net webApi project which is depending on a third-party framework that does a lot of stuff with HttpContext.Current which does not exists in Asp.net Core. That is why I could not create Asp.net Core Web Application targeting .net full framework.

So I created old-school Asp.net Web Application project with WebApi extension.

Now I am trying to use Microsoft.Extension.DependencyInjection framework with it.

I found [this](http://scottdorman.github.io/2016/03/17/integrating-asp.net-core-dependency-injection-in-mvc-4/) example for Asp.Net Mvc4 but my project is WebApi. That approach did not work. Can anyone provide link or code snippet for me to move forward?

P.S: When providing an example, please make sure it should not use OWIN framework. Because when I tried to use OWIN pipeline, the third-party library(closed source) is not working properly.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I also found [that](https://scottdorman.blog/2016/03/17/integrating-asp-net-core-dependency-injection-in-mvc-4/) example a while ago, i make it work perfect both in
Asp.Net Mvc4 and WebApi2 project.

Use some IoC container (eg. Unity, Autofac) for WebApi project, the most important thing is implementing the interface **IDependencyResolver** to make your own dependency resolver.

Hers's my code snippet for WebApi project.

*WebApiConfig*

```cs
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ...

        // using Microsoft.Extension.DependencyInjection here.
        Startup.Bootstrapper(config);
    }
}
```

*Startup*

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public static void Bootstrapper(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var provider = Configuration();
        var resolver = new DefaultDependencyResolver(provider);

        config.DependencyResolver = resolver;
    }

    private static IServiceProvider Configuration()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.AddControllersAsServices(typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetExportedTypes()
            .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract && !t.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
            .Where(t => typeof(IHttpController).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                        || t.Name.EndsWith("Controller", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));

        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        return serviceProvider;
    }
}
```

*DefaultDependencyResolver*

```cs
public class DefaultDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private IServiceScope serviceScope;
    protected IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }

    public DefaultDependencyResolver(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.ServiceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return this.ServiceProvider.GetService(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return this.ServiceProvider.GetServices(serviceType);
    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        serviceScope = this.ServiceProvider.CreateScope();
        return new DefaultDependencyResolver(serviceScope.ServiceProvider);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // you can implement this interface just when you use .net core 2.0
        // this.ServiceProvider.Dispose();

        //need to dispose the scope otherwise
        //you'll get a memory leak
        serviceScope?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

*ServiceProviderExtensions*

```cs
public static class ServiceProviderExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddControllersAsServices(this IServiceCollection services,
        IEnumerable<Type> controllerTypes)
    {
        foreach (var type in controllerTypes)
        {
            services.AddTransient(type);
        }

        return services;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I was a bit late to confirm it.

Comment: This was great and worked, but one small suggestion: it's not clear that any instance/type that you want to inject into your controller's constructor, *also* needs to be added to the services collection. From my limited testing, it appears the resolver needs both the "injectibles", and "injectees" added as services.

Comment: Excellent answer @Hin Liang

Comment: In .net 4.x with both mvc and web api in the same app, setting just HttpConfiguration.DependencyResolver only worked for web api for me, for mvc I had to also set the System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver which uses System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver which is different to  System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver. Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494920/

Comment: How does this handle per-request scoping?