# Posting from web role to another web role Windows Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I currently have two web roles in my solution, one for the main web app and another which I'd like to act as an API for both the web app and for mobile applications.

They both work independently of each other but I am struggling to post data from a view in the web app's role to an API controller in the API's role.

This is the method in the API controller:

```
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    var post = (Post)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(value, typeof(Post));
    AddPost(post);
}
```

And here is the JavaScript from the view I am trying to post from:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var onPost = function () {
            $.post("http://localhost:8081/api/Post",
                {
                    "value": $('#postForm').serialize()
                }
            ).success(function () {
                alert("SUCCESS");
            }).fail(function () {
                alert("FAILURE");
            });
        };
    });
</script>
```

Edit:

I am not getting an error, nor are either of the alert functions being called. However, on clicking the button which fires this event, the URL changes to include the entries of the form that has been serialized.

Comment: It might help if you provided more information as to what behavior you are getting.  Are you getting an error?  Also, in your ajax post on the fail callback you could get more error information. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ for more information on getting the jqXHR so you can see what error you are actually getting.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with regards to the fail callback. Unfortunately, it isn't being called. I've updated the post to explain further.

Comment: Seems to be a cross domain call issue. Try do do POST directly using tool like Fiddler. If you are able to do it, read about how to make cross domain ajax requests.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to make the API call from server side such as MVC controller in your web app. You can include security key and other things that you don't want to expose to others. When you make API call directly from javascript for another subdomain or url, you are creating cross-domain ajax request.

In your javascript, you will make an ajax call to your controller action in your web app. Web app will make the call to whatever service it is talking to.

You can also test your API from fiddler with POSt/GEt/PUt/DELETE requests.

If you want to directly call from javascript and host web roles under different subdomains, you need to make CORS request: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/. You can also look at this related question: [Running WebApi alongside MVC project in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650748/running-webapi-alongside-mvc-project-in-azure)