# how to host webapplication and webapi in single solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

I created a solution with two webapplication project. One is asp.net mvc and second one is web api. Now I want to publish. Kindly suggest me how to publish my webapplication and webapi

Answer (score 0):

all mvc pages, web api controllers and aspx pages can be added to single project, no need to different project, if you need to seperate business you can use areas and class libraries

Answer (score 0):

**Process 1 :**

You don't need to create separate project for Web API and MVC application in a single solution. You can create a MVC application and add an **WebApiConfig.cs** (route for api) file in **App_Start folder**. Write the **route** for API,(you just need to copy your route from Web API project and paste here). Now you can add/keep your all Api controllers in Controller folder which must be inherited from **ApiController**. That's it!

**Process 2 :**

But if you want to keep in separate project in a single solution,

then right click on your solution -> click on properties -> It will open property page. Here select the Multiple Startup projects radio button -> Then you can set both MVC and Web API application as start in action column -> Click on Apply -> Then Ok.

Suppose your Domain name is example.com. Then you can publish your MVC application there. And create a **sub-domain**, for example, myapi.example.com, and publish your API there. Then enable CORS on API project.

I would recommend to go with Process 1.

If you want to know more about how to publish both project from a single solution, please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383705/mvc-and-web-api-projects-in-the-same-solution)

Comment: But How to publish and host my web application.

Comment: As I stated, it's very easy to keep your both projects in a single one then publish.

Comment: I have done above given process.                                                                                                                         Right click on your solution -> click on properties -> It will open property page. Here select the Multiple Startup projects radio button -> Then you can set both MVC and Web API application as start in action column -> Click on Apply -> Then Ok                                                                  Then publish web application. But I have one issue. In my web application I am using web api url "http://localhost:51673/".

Comment: Ok. Are you able to publish ?

Comment: It show only one application. but not show web api.