# Add Web Api controllers to an existing ASP.NET 4 web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Following the steps from this question [How to add Web API to an existing ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990036/how-to-add-web-api-to-an-existing-asp-net-mvc-4-web-application-project) , I have added web api support to my application.

In my original scenario I have the following web mvc controller:

```
public class FranchiseController : Controller
    {


        public ActionResult List()
        {
            return View();
        }



        [DataContext]
        public ActionResult GetAllFranchises()
        {
            var franchiseInfoViewModelList = new List<FranchiseInfoViewModel>();

            var franchiseInfoList = _franchiseService.GetAll();

            foreach (var franchiseInfo in franchiseInfoList)
            {
                franchiseInfoViewModelList.Add(new FranchiseInfoViewModel(franchiseInfo, p => p.IsImportant));
            }

            var jsonNetResult = new JsonNetResult
            {
                Formatting = Formatting.Indented, 
                Data = franchiseInfoViewModelList
            };

            return jsonNetResult;
        }
    }
```

When the user navigates to the List view, I am calling

```
 $.getJSON("/franchise/GetAllFranchises")
                .done(function (data) {

                });
```

to go to the `GetAllFranchises` action method and return the json data. So far so good.

I have created the following web api controller:

```
public class FranchiseController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<FranchiseInfoViewModel> GetAllFranchises()
        {
            var allFranchises = new List<FranchiseInfoViewModel>();

            var franchiseInfoList = _franchiseService.GetAll();

            foreach (var franchiseInfo in franchiseInfoList)
            {
                allFranchises.Add(new FranchiseInfoViewModel(franchiseInfo, p => p.IsImportant));
            }

            return allFranchises;
        }
    }
```

and I am trying to get to its action method like this:

```
$.getJSON("api/franchise")
                .done(function (data) {

                });
```

I am getting 404 error and the app is trying to reach the following url:

```
/Franchise/api/franchise
```

instead of `api/franchise`.

Global Asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            Log.StartSession();
            ElmahExtension.SetCurrentApplication(this);

            ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new OmegaViewEngine());
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            SerializerConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
            Bootstrapper.Initialise();
            FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure();

        }
```

Default route:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

In my Controllers folder I have my web mvc controller:

```
Controller\FranchiseController
```

and I have made a new folder WebAPI to hold my web api controller

```
Controller\WebAPI\FranchiseController
```

What am I doing wrong ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the right move to name "FranchiseController" both to the MVC Internet Application Controller and to the MVC Web API Controller (totally different things). After renaming one of them I think you should put the Web Api Controller in the root of the directory (Controller).