# Error with WebApi 2.0 RouteAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api2

Here's my Global.asax

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RegisterRoutes();
    }

    private static void RegisterRoutes()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(x => x.MapHttpAttributeRoutes());
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();
    }
```

Here's my Web Api controller

```
    [RoutePrefix("api/admin/users/")]
    public class UsersController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("get")]
        public IQueryable<User> GetUsers()
        {
            return db.Users;
        }
    }
```

And here's the error I get when I navigate to localhost:123/api/admin/users/get

`The object has not yet been initialized. Ensure that HttpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized() is called in the application's startup code after all other initialization code.`

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. I believe that I'm doing everything properly for the new WebApi 2.0 way, but I'm missing something.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Here's the stack in-case it helps

```
at System.Web.Http.Routing.RouteCollectionRoute.GetRouteData(String virtualPathRoot, HttpRequestMessage request) 
at System.Web.Http.WebHost.Routing.HttpWebRoute.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
```

Comment: Can you share your webapiconfig.cs file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please remove

```
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(x => x.MapHttpAttributeRoutes());
```

from ***Global.asax***.

And then call `MapHttpAttributeRoutes` in the ***WebApiConfig.cs***

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }
```

Comment: Just tried this out this morning. Not sure that I understand why the call needs to be made inside of the WebApiConfig.cs but this fixed the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it by convention? What does name of whateverConfig.cs matter?

Comment: Could have something to do with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34325083/1516678) - basically the routes must be mapped before GlobalConfiguration.Configure is called.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was getting this error because I was configuring Autofac before WebApi:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(AutofacConfig.Register);
```

Changing the order got me past that issue:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(AutofacConfig.Register);
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```