# Attribute Routing doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm creating a rest api in visual studio express 2013.

I have 2 controllers: one for orders and one for clients.

I've already created the following:

`/api/clients` GET information about all clients

`/api/clients/1` GET information about client with id = 1

`/api/orders/10` GET information about order with id = 10

Now, I want to create this:

`/api/clients/1/orders` - GET information about all orders of client with id 1

I've read about attribute routing, but I can't make it work.

OrdersController.cs

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class OrdersController : ApiController
{
    public Order Get(string id)
    {
        // ...
    }

    [Route("clients/{id}/orders")]
    public List<Order> GetByClient(string id)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Enable CORS
        config.EnableCors();

        //config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Like this, all of the other requests work properly, but when I try to access `/api/clients/1/orders`, I get the error `HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found. The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

But as soon as I uncomment `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`, I'm no longer able to access any of the requests - they all return this:

```
<Error>
    <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
    The object has not yet been initialized. Ensure that HttpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized() is called in the application's startup code after all other initialization code.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
    at System.Web.Http.Routing.RouteCollectionRoute.get_SubRoutes() at System.Web.Http.Routing.RouteCollectionRoute.GetRouteData(String virtualPathRoot, HttpRequestMessage request) at System.Web.Http.WebHost.Routing.HttpWebRoute.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
</StackTrace>
</Error>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try uncommenting `//config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`

Comment: You are also missing a `[HttpGet]` attribute on the `GetByClient` action in `OrdersController`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya did you even read what I wrote?

Comment: @Nkosi My question is clear. I state what I have, what I want, and what my problem is. Not sure what it is you're not understanding. Also, [HttpGet] shouldn't be needed, as the method name starts with Get.

Comment: I missed the last part. Sorry if I offended you. I am sure you tried the suggestion mentioned in the exception too. If not you can follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19969228/ensure-that-httpconfiguration-ensureinitialized

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25066147/error-with-webapi-2-0-routeattribute

Comment: Other potential reason is that the Controller class does not end in "Controller".  E.g.: "SomethingApi.cs" instead of "SomethingApiController.cs".  Surely not the issue in this question, but google keeps bringing me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncomment your `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()` line, then in your Global.asax file, replace this:

```
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

with this:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

You can read about it here:

[Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Comment: This fixed the problem of not being able to access any of the requests, however, as pointed out by the other user, i still had the route path wrong. I wish I could appoint both of your answers as accepted... Thank you!

Comment: The path would have never worked without you fixing the configuration. Your real issue was the global.asax.

Answer (score 3):

With routing attribute `[Route("clients/{id}/orders")]`, you should access action `GetByClient()` not by `/api/clients/1/orders` url, but with `/clients/1/orders`. To have an original url just fix the routing:

```
[Route("api/clients/{id}/orders")]
public List<Order> GetByClient(string id)
```

Comment: It solved it, thank you :)