# A "direct route" AND "The object has not yet been initialized" errors, WebAPI

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web Api project on Visual Studio 2013.
suddenly, I started getting this error, without doing any change:

> A direct route cannot use the parameter 'controller'. Specify a
>   literal path in place of this parameter to create a route to a
>   controller.
>
> ```
> > Line 12:     protected void Application_Start() 
> > Line 13:     {
> > Line 14:      GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); 
> > Line 15:      GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always; 
> > Line 16:      GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();
> ```

When I refresh the page I get another error:

> {   "message": "An error has occurred.",   "exceptionMessage": "The
>   object has not yet been initialized. Ensure that
>   HttpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized() is called in the application's
>   startup code after all other initialization code.",   "exceptionType":
>   "System.InvalidOperationException",   "stackTrace": "   at
>   System.Web.Http.Routing.RouteCollectionRoute.get_SubRoutes()\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Routing.RouteCollectionRoute.GetRouteData(String
>   virtualPathRoot, HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.WebHost.Routing.HttpWebRoute.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext)" }

This is my WebApiConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {


        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

My Global.asax.cs:

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();
    }
```

And this is my test function on my Test Controller:

```
  public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
```

Please advise, any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: What is the name of your Controller, and what is the path you are using to test it?

Comment: The name of my Controller is: Test. and this is the link: http://../../.../test/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching the Internet for a very long time without finding a solution, I recreated the project from scratch and that solved the issue.
It seems to be some kind of bug in Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to comment out the following from your WebApiConfig:

```
// config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
//    name: "DefaultApi",
//    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
//    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
//);
```

Then ensure that your route attributes are set on your controller as so:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/test")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    };

}
```

And then place a call to:

> http://**myapiurl**/api/test/1

Comment: or set the routeTemplate to: `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}"`

Comment: There will be quite a few ways to achieve the same thing when it comes to WebAPI routes, but I prefer attribute convention - especially for troubleshooting - being explicit with routes has helped me figure out lots of issues, especially when controllers get big.

Comment: I suppose so, on the other hand I find that having attributes everywhere annoys me somewhat... Each to their own.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried what you suggested but i'm still getting the same error. everything worked perfectly before I got these errors, I don't know why it started erroring...

Comment: Something must have changed to trigger these errors. Googling the message I see it can be caused by a variety of issues, I guess you'll just have to rule all of them out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19969228/ensure-that-httpconfiguration-ensureinitialized

Comment: You are right, I tried everything I found but nothing helped!

Comment: I ended up re-creating the project.. That solved the issue!

Comment: Hah, typical VS. You should answer your own question with some details of exactly what you did and mark it as correct :)