# Create a RestFul Service in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, rest

Is there a way I can create a RestFul Service as part of my MVC 4 web application. I already have one ASP.net MVC4 web application. I can create a new project with VS2013 to write a new service. But I don't want to create a new project, is there a way to utilize the same existing project for this?

I am looking for service which uses Web API

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990036/how-to-add-web-api-to-an-existing-asp-net-mvc-4-web-application-project

Comment: @Wesz-T I am using VS 2010

Comment: Your Web API is itself RESTFul service. You can add Web API controller from VS. Even you can find EF/Action Scaffolded Web API Template from VS Online Templates Gallery from Extension Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this library for .NET https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack .

It is a free if you are using branch v3 form a github.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at OWIN and Katana. You can use it to set up webapi in your current MVC project. [Here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api) is an example How to do it.