# Make Web api 2 to use mvc 5 credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a MVC 5 application and I can register a user.

Now, I want to access a Web Api 2 with these credentials. 
I added Web api 2 just like in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990036/how-to-add-web-api-to-an-existing-asp-net-mvc-4-web-application-project)

And this is my api

```
public class MyApiController : ApiController
{
    [Authorize]
    //[System.Web.Mvc.Authorize]
    public ResultContainer Get()
    {
        var result = new ResultContainer 
        {
            IsOk = true,
            DisplayMessage = false,
        };
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now, I want to access the api with a .net client (.net 4) with an account I registered from the website.

This is the code

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password) };
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseUri) })
            {
                try
                {
                    var response = client.GetAsync("/api/MyApi").Result;  // Blocking call!
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    }
                 }
             }
```

The problem is that I always receive an html page with the form to login instead of the resource I wanted.
I can access the api if I don't set the

> Authorize

attribute.
What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the Owin Authentication Pipeline? They can be shared easily across the two technologies.

Comment: Can we see the code you're using to access the API?

Comment: @Simon can you share a link? Thanks ;)

Comment: @Erik the code I'm using to access the API is the second code in the thread

Comment: @Daniel A good start would be [A primer on OWIN cookie authentication middleware for the ASP.NET developer](http://brockallen.com/2013/10/24/a-primer-on-owin-cookie-authentication-middleware-for-the-asp-net-developer/)

Comment: Is it possible to use the "old" way with NetworkCredential?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to pass network credentials with each API call?

Comment: I would like to understand how it works if I want to try another option