# Best way to expose services from .net to be used by mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, .net, performance, windows-phone

I'm going to create an app for iOS, Android and Windows Phone that will expose the same features that is currently available from our website which is currently being re-developed, and one of the main feature is a search feature. The website along with all the layers are all built with .net (4.5.2) and sql server and we need to expose all the services to be consumed by the mobile apps. The good thing is that it's up to me to decide how they should be exposed, but I'm not sure what's the best technology/protocol to use. What I've been told it should meet is performance/responsiveness. I thought about exposing the services as a WebAPI layer but I'm not sure if it's the best way to achieve such a requirement.

What would you recommend? Does anybody have bone through a situation like this?

Answer (score 1):

Adding an api layer to an existing web application is pretty easy and I think is perfect for your needs. That way you can essentially wrap your existing functionality with the api.

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990036/how-to-add-web-api-to-an-existing-asp-net-mvc-4-web-application-project)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are redeveloping the server side, I would take a close look at [Azure Mobile Services](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/mobile-services/). If that doesn't work for you, and you need something more *custom developed*, I would still consider Azure hosting with a Web API layer - Web API is definitely the way to go here as it provides easy way to exchange mobile-friendly JSON with a thin layer over your services.

By the way, for **any** new .NET development, I would go with [ASP.NET vNEXT](http://www.asp.net/vnext)

Comment: isn't vNext still in preview since it's packaged with VS2015?  I thought it was recommended by Microsoft that it was not "production ready"?

Comment: That will be true right up until the moment that it isn't (which will be soon)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are targeting multiple clients, you should expose your business as restful services that return data as `JSON` and also I would recommend using `OData` (Open Data Protocol) which is an `OASIS` standard that defines the best practice for building and consuming `RESTFul` API.

Also `OData` provide useful querying techniques for example the following `URL` will return first 2 persons in the system who have registered at least one trip that costs more than 3000, and only display their first name and last name

http://services.odata.org/v4/TripPinServiceRW/People?$top=2&$select=FirstName,LastName&$filter=Trips/any(d:d/Budget gt 3000)

For more information about `OData` please check http://www.odata.org/

Comment: That's what Web API is... it implements OData!

Comment: @GregEnnis Web API is not one to one with OData however you can use the Web API to expose OData services, i.e I can use Web APIs without applying OData