# How do you add a Web Api Controller to an MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I've created a default MVC 5 Web application and want to allow clients to call that API.  For reasons too long to get into, I really need to keep the API as part of the application.  I first added an additional controller to the default solution called **FooController** that returns a View with some dummy data.  This should have no bearing on the Web API, but I wanted to make sure I could at least add a MVC controller.  I can run the solution and when browse to http://localhost:54110/Foo my dummy data is returned

In a separate solution, I was able to use [Getting Started with ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) to create an API.  I'm able to call the api using:  http://localhost:47503/api/products/2 which sends me a json file.  All is good.

I went back to my first project and repeated the steps for creating the Web API2, however when I try and call the API via http://localhost:54110/api/products/2 I'm getting a 404.  Obviously I have a routing problem.

Here is my `Application_Start`, where I added last line to call `GlobalConfiguration` as that is what is used in the Web API sample.

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
```

and here is the Register method from `WebApiConfig`

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

I *know* this is being called, because the debugger is breaking on this method.  Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?  Is there a way to trace what is happening when I hit *ENTER* after http://localhost:54110/api/products/2 ?

Comment: what does your mvc routing look like? also what does the method from your api look like?

Comment: This help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990036/how-to-add-web-api-to-an-existing-asp-net-mvc-4-web-application-project

Comment: It's possible you just haven't set something up right, but given that you're still in a very early stage of development here, it seems more trouble than it's worth to try to figure out what if anything is misconfigured. Create a new project and add both Web Api and MVC from the start. Then, just move over what little code you've developed.

Comment: Doh!  -- I didn't notice that option.  I'll check it out later.

Comment: It would be good if you provide action methods. 404 might also be because action methods, parameters binding mismatc. How are you testing the api url??