# Include Web API in existing Asp.Net MVC project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a project with asp.net mvc architecture. I would like to add services with the asp.net web api. How can I incorporate it into the exist project?

Comment: What do you mean "How can I incorporate"?

Comment: Do you use any IoC container in existing MVC  application?

Comment: I would like to add web API to exist project. But I do not know what files I should add and what settings I should make...

Comment: No i have never used IoC.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to add Web API to an existing ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990036/how-to-add-web-api-to-an-existing-asp-net-mvc-4-web-application-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ASP.NET MVC 4, the easiest way is to create a new Web API project in Visual Studio 2015, and see how the project is set up.

[image]

Basically, you just need to add the following packages as of today, and the following codes -

### Packages

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost
```

### Global.asax.cs

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        ...
    }
}
```

### App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

### Testing

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to this, it is important to place GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); before RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);, otherwise while calling api, 404 will be returned