# How to Add token authentication to web api in cookie authentication based asp.net mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have this asp.net mvc project that uses cookie based authentication and i added a web api endpoint to it following [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990036/how-to-add-web-api-to-an-existing-asp-net-mvc-4-web-application-project). It worked like a charm but when i decorate the api controller with an `[Authorize]`, the requests fail to authenticate even when I provide username and password in postman. I would like the `ApiController` to allow token based authentication while keeping the cookie based authentication in the mvc part. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: token based authentication -> JWT or OAuth?

Comment: OAuth token based authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have separate projects in your applications for Web API and MVC.

In the Web API project, if you create a project with authentication as 'Individual User Accounts', it automatically adds OAuth files and related code to the project. If you create a project with No Authentication, you have to add the Owin Middleware to access OAuth feature.

You will be looking at these settings in Statup.Auth.cs file.
[image]

On the MVC side, the default authentication is cookie based. To call your Web APIs, you have to use **HTTPClient**. This should return a token which you can add to your **DefaultRequestHeaders** like this (I am using this approach).
[image]

Other option is to store the token in Sessions or add it to the Authentication Cookie.

I hope you will find this helpful.:)

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2019 when you create a Web API project template and select Individual User Accounts for Authentication, the vs implement a Token-Based Authentication for you very similar to this [Article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1187872/Token-Based-Authentication-for-Web-API-where-Legac). the only difference is that the article uses a legacy table for storing user data and Microsoft's code uses the famous AspNetUsers table. I strongly recommend you to follow the article and at the end replace the GrantResourceOwnerCredentials method in the ApplicationOAuthProvider file with the following code:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }

        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
           OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
        context.Validated(ticket);
        context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
    }
```