# Why does Newtonsoft.JSON put a '$' sign in each property of each element?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

I have been using **JSON** from the King for a long time, and I have just noticed, that he adds for each element that is a **property name** :

```
{ "$id": "1", "BackGroundColor": "#FFFFFF", "PageTitleFontColor": "#9C0912", "TitleDescriptionFontColor": "#715135", "TextTitleFontColor": "#715135", "ContentFontColor": "#646464", "VisiblePages": { "$id": "2", "$values": [ "About", "Gallery", "PriceList" ] } }
```

This is how I set it up:

```
JsonSerializerSettings jSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
   PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All,
   Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
   DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc,
   ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
};

jSettings.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = jSettings;

config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

The models example:

```
public class SettingsApiModel
{
    public virtual string BackGroundColor { get; set; }
    public virtual string PageTitleFontColor { get; set; }
    public virtual string TitleDescriptionFontColor { get; set; }
    public virtual string TextTitleFontColor { get; set; }
    public virtual string ContentFontColor { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<string> VisiblePages { get; set; } 
}
```

I actually don't like the '$' on each property. How can I remove it?

Comment: I've not seen this before - could you give a *complete* example?

Comment: Elvis used JSON?

Comment: My Newtonsoft.Json doesn't do that?

Comment: Have you decorated your `values` property with this attribute `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$values")]`?

Comment: Nope haven't done anything like that

Comment: Could you post the code of the class that is serialized into the JSON in your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the `PreserveReferencesHandling` property you are using in the `jSettings` object. You can either not set this at all, or set it to `PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects`.

No `PreserveReferencesHandling` setting:

```
{
    "BackGroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "PageTitleFontColor": "#9C0912",
    "TitleDescriptionFontColor": "#715135",
    "TextTitleFontColor": "#715135",
    "ContentFontColor": "#646464",
    "VisiblePages": [
        "About",
        "Gallery",
        "PriceList"
    ]
}
```

`PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects`

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "BackGroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "PageTitleFontColor": "#9C0912",
    "TitleDescriptionFontColor": "#715135",
    "TextTitleFontColor": "#715135",
    "ContentFontColor": "#646464",
    "VisiblePages": [
        "About",
        "Gallery",
        "PriceList"
    ]
}
```

Comment: How do i handle the circular references, than?

Comment: hey m8 this what helped me to solve it,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847564/how-do-i-get-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-chrome