# Choosing JSON or XML

Tags: xml, json, asp.net-web-api

With Web Api, how can I allow the user to choose whether they get JSON or XML back from the web service?

Comment: You can change return type on demand. Already answered at http://stackoverflow.com/a/12487921/929902

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web API out of the box allows the client to choose what format they want back from the server. They can send:

```
Accept: application/json
```

in the HTTP header to get JSON back, and:

```
Accept: application/xml
```

to get XML back. JSON is the default if no Accept header is specified.

This is referred to as content negotiation and you can learn more about it here:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation