# How to make ASP.NET Web API to only return XML?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to send a get request to ASP.NET Web API and get back a XML to parse it in my Android app. it returns XML when I try the link via web browser, but it return JSON when Android app send the request. how to fix it in a way it only sends XML? thanks

Comment: Probably duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847564/how-do-i-get-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-chrome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could remove the JSON formatter if you don't intend to serve JSON:

```
var formatters = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters;
formatters.Remove(formatters.JsonFormatter);
```

You also have the possibility to explicitly specify the formatter to be used in your action:

```
public object Get()
{
    var model = new 
    {
        Foo = "bar"
    };

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, model, Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
}
```

Comment: Changing the formatters collection is probably the best way, but I would be tempted to clear the collection and add back an XmlFormatter.

Answer (score 3):

You could also force the accept header on all requests to be `application/xml` by using a MessageHandler

```
public class ForceXmlHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.Headers.Accept.Clear();
        request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Just add this message handler to the configuration object.

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new ForceXmlHandler());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove JSON formatter them in `Application_Start`

Use

`GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter);`