# ASP.NET web api returning XML instead of JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I read that by default, Web API will return JSON Data but for some reason when creating an API, it returns XML instead of JSON.

```
public class CurrencyController : ApiController
{
    private CompanyDatabaseContext db = new CompanyDatabaseContext();

    // GET api/Currency
    public IEnumerable<Currency> GetCurrencies()
    {
        return db.Currencies.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

I haven't modified anything out of the ordinary so I'm stumped

Comment: Nevermind, I found out it was actually returning JSON, for some reason Chrome was formatting it into XML >>

Comment: Possible duplication: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847564/how-do-i-get-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-chrome)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

if you modify your **WebApiConfig** as follows you'll get JSON by default.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the explanation here?  the last two lines are removing the xml formatter?

Comment: Lovely, if you want to remove XML support (even when explicitly requested) and want this on all responses, Seems impossible to find information on how to enforce it on only one endpoint :/

Comment: Exactly what I was lookin' for !!

Answer (score 18):

Web Api looks for the headers of the upcoming request to choose the returning data type. For instance, if you set **Accept:application/json** it will automatically set the returning type to JSON.

Besides that, setting content-type gives a clue to Web-API about upcoming request data type. So if you want to post JSON data to Web API you should have **Content-Type:application/json** in header.