# Web api should return JSon by default

Tags: xml, json, asp.net-web-api2

This is what I have currently

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(new QueryStringMapping("type", "json", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")));             

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(new QueryStringMapping("type", "xml", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml")));
```

it works fine when I call API with query like this

```
for xml : http://localhost:49533/api/?type=xml
for json: http://localhost:49533/api/?type=json
```

but what I want is JSON by default? is that possible? I want above options available as well

Comment: it should've returned Json by default..

Comment: its returning xml by default

Comment: When I request like this - http://localhost:49533/api/Product  I get XML

Comment: how you checked, using browser? was it chrome? see OP's comment here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266952/asp-net-web-api-returning-xml-instead-of-json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content negotiation looks at several things in your request including the Accept header (but also the contenttype header to infer returned results). If your request has XML in the accept header then it will go to XML.

Below is the chrome default headers, note that it's asking for XML, hence Web API will return XML by default for chrome.

{Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html, **application/xhtml+xml, application/xml;** q=0.9, image/webp, */*; q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US, en; q=0.8
Host: localhost:63586
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36
}

You can choose in your application to ignore the accept headers, by removing them from the formatters:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Clear();
```

Then add your query mapping (similarly of course for the XML formatter).