# Return JSON from Web API that makes asynchronous call to Odata endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am building a Web API which makes a asynchronous call to the Odata endpoint. The odata endpoint returns JSON, and I am trying to return the same JSON from the Web API too. Since I am calling the Odata endpoint asynchronously I am using Task as return type my API method but I want to return them as JSON and I am not sure how I can do that.Below is my code

```
   public async Task<string> GetEmployee(string instance)
    {
       .....
        EmployeeDTO.RootObject returnObj = new EmployeeDTO.RootObject();
        var responsedata = "";
        try
        {
        using (var client_Core = new HttpClient())
            {
               ....
                string core_URL = BaseURL_Core+URL_instance;
                var response = client_Core.GetAsync(core_URL).Result;

                responsedata = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
              }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return responsedata;
```

Currently it returns like

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
 {
       "@odata.context":"https://science.com/odata/$metadata#EMPLOYEE",
"value":[
       { 
        "Id":5000004, 
        "Name":"Account", 
        "Barcode":"EM1"
       }]
    }
 </string>
```

I am trying to avoid the string tag around the JSON response. How acn we do that

[image]

Comment: What's the content type you requested? Web API's responses are converted to the requested format if they're objects and one of the requested formats is supported.

Comment: Why does ASP.NET MVC belong to this question?

Comment: If the service only returns xml then you could simply parse the response as xml and extract the json from the `<string>` element. Incidentally, you don't need to block with `.Result` if you are in an async method, you should `await`. Also [try not to new up an `HttpClient` for each request](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Comment: @Crowcoder Thanks for you suggestion on the HttpClient I will fix that. I am not doing anyother manipulation in my API and the other application that will call my API can only consume JSON. How can I have a JSON response. Should I change the `Task<string>` anyother format?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I havenot added the content type in my API, where should I be adding that?

Comment: I think that the default is XML. Try to set the content type to `application/json`.

Comment: If it won't work, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266952/asp-net-web-api-returning-xml-instead-of-json. This is a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the API can return JSON and it is just a matter of changing the Content-Type as suggested by Chayim.

But if it will only return xml, you could do this:

```
...
string core_URL = BaseURL_Core+URL_instance;
var response = await client_Core.GetAsync(core_URL);
string xml = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument doc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(xml);
responsedata = doc.Root.Value;
...
```

Comment: If I am not using `.result` in `await client_Core.GetAsync(core_URL)` I am getting error in the below line like `'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>' does not contain a definition for 'Content' and no extension method 'Content' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Are you sure you are using `await`? That is the error you would get if you omitted the `await` keyword.

Comment: @trx Thank you. You did **not** add `await` to `client_Core.GetAsync(core_URL)`

Comment: Getting an error while Parsing `$exception {"Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."} System.Exception {System.Xml.XmlException}`

Comment: @trx That code worked for me based on the xml in your original question. I see you asked another question and your system has now been modified so I don't know the current state of the response. What exactly is the string value of `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` now?