# How to convert JSON response to XML in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, xml

I have an API response in JSON format, how can I convert it to XML response in c#

i don't know the placement of the script to convert JSON to XML

```
public static async Task<List<PointMaster>> ExecuteTest(string query)
        {
            string connStrResult = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PostGresConnection"].ConnectionString;
            NpgsqlConnection connection;
            NpgsqlCommand command;
            NpgsqlDataReader reader;

            List<PointMaster> master = new List<PointMaster>();
            connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connStrResult);
            connection.Open();
            command = new NpgsqlCommand(query, connection);
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (await reader.ReadAsync())
            {
                PointMaster point = new PointMaster
                {
                    point_id        = Convert.ToString(reader["point_id"]),
                    point_type      = (string)reader["point_type"],
                    sp_geometry     = (PostgisPoint)(reader["sp_geometry"]),
                    msid            = Convert.ToInt32(reader["msid"]),

                };

                master.Add(point);
            }

            return master;
        }
```

I want that response to be changed to XML

Comment: Have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266952/asp-net-web-api-returning-xml-instead-of-json and the question that it links to as well. I think you will find what you are looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET web api returning XML instead of JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266952/asp-net-web-api-returning-xml-instead-of-json)

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Global.asax` and but following code in `Application_Start()` :

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseDataContractSerializer = true;
```

Or go to `WebApiConfig.cs`  and put this line in `Register(HttpConfiguration config)` :

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(  
        new QueryStringMapping("type", "xml", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml")));
```

Comment: N.b. this doesn't turn JSON *into* XML, it generates XML *instead of* JSON. There is never any JSON, This is the right way to achieve what the OP actually wants, just not literally what they said.