# Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html

Tags: ios, ios7, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am working on an iOS app, using web-service.
For call my web-service i decided to use AFNetWorking 2.0.
And i have a big issue :
On the command line i use curl :

```
    curl -X POST -d '[{"username":"user123","password":"querty"}]' -H "Content-Type:          application/json" http://mysite
```

This works perfectly.

Now when i want to use on iOS App:

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];


    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json; text/html" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json; text/html; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username": @"user123", @"password":@"querty"};

    [manager POST:@"http://mysite" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

i got this error :
        Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html

Comment: use this [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];      
// [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
  NSLog(@"POST called with param : %@",parameter);
 [manager POST:requestURL parameters:parameter success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i have the same error. And i have this for the parameters : POST called with param : {
    password = querty;
    username = "user123";
}

Comment: try this.i think ur server is sending "text/html", and this type is not supported by default. Add @"text/html" for "acceptableContentTypes" manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

Comment: i got this error : JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x8d3fc70 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set., NSUnderlyingError=0x8d41610 "Request failed: unsupported media type (415)

Comment: I think your Json is the problem.[{"username":"value", "password":"value"}]

Comment: i think so, but passe it directly to the parameters to AfNetWorking. The web service need a parameter on json format.

Comment: Try this NSLog(@"POST JSON: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);NSError *error = nil;
NSMutableDictionary  * json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
NSLog(@"%@",json);
if(error){
if(self.delegate) [self.delegate requestFailedWithError:error forAPI:requestName];            
}else{     
if(self.delegate) [self.delegate parsedResponse:responseObject forAPI:requestName];
}

Comment: same error 415. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: check your key is in string format.

Comment: Check this link too.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874935/afnetworking-2-0-post-issue-cocoa-error-3840json-text-did-not-start-with-array?rq=1

Comment: It always doesn't work. On android this very simple code above works perfectly. **HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri[0]);
httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri[0]);
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("username", "papa1@free.fr");
json.put("password", "aaaaaa");
StringEntity se = new StringEntity( json.toString());
se.setContentType(newBasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json"));
post.setEntity(se);**

Comment: I cant able to answer here.Otherwise i can post my code .Check this linkhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186754/how-to-create-simple-http-request-via-afnetworking