# Swagger Code Generation incompatible?

Tags: swagger-2.0

I have a swagger API that I am generating client and server code from.

The client code uses the 'Angular Typescript' option; the server uses the 'node.js' option.

The problem I am having is that the client code models' properties are being generated in **camel case** (e.g. firstName) and the server models' properties are being generated as **pascal case** (e.g. FirstName).

The models I have defined inside the spec use **pascal case**.

Because of the different casings, I am having issues referencing the properties.

Is there a simple way (i.e. not modifying the swagger code gen source) to have the generator respect the names that are defined in the swagger document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be fixed in an upcoming swagger-codegen 2.1.6. There's a [commit](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/pull/1965) that allows to change property naming convention.

As a workaround you can also change your server API implementation to support the camel cased property deserialization.

Comment: 2 questions please: 1) When do you expect 2.1.6 to release? 2) How do I change the server API implementation?

Comment: 1) I'm not aware of swagger release milestones but I think it's not far away. 2) You can adjust your API serializer settings (there's an example for asp.net webapi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445730/how-can-i-return-camelcase-json-serialized-by-json-net-from-asp-net-mvc-controll)

Comment: In regards to my question #2 I thought you meant there was a way for the node server code gen to support the camel cased deserialization. I'm generating for client and server apps in this project so no .NET MVC.