# JSON returns properties in PascalCase instead of camelCase

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

Using `Microsoft.AspNetCOre.OData 7.0.1`, if I have a list of Models that are NOT in the database, the JSON result always comes back as PascalCase instead of camelCase. How can I get my list to be camelCase?

Relative example below:

My model that is NOT in the database.

```
public class Widget 
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class WidgetController : ODataController 
{
    [EnableQuery()]
    public IActionResult GetWidgets() 
    {
        // Create list of ten Widgets
        var widgetsList = new List<Widget>();

        for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            widgetsList.Add(new Widget() { Id = i, Name = $"Widget {i}" });
        }

        return this.Ok(widgetsList);
    }       
}
```

/api/GetWidgets?$select=name returns in the following format

```
{ Name: "Widget" }
```

Comment: Since both `Id` and `Name` are `private` (so they wouldn't be serialized to JSON at all), the returned data does not match your code. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: You need explicit Json converter to convert the result to the relevant case

Comment: You can use json.net by newtonsoft to serialize into camelCase. Great set of answers here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445730/how-can-i-return-camelcase-json-serialized-by-json-net-from-asp-net-mvc-controll

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Option 1

Even though `Widget` is not in the database, you can add it to the Entity Data Model (EDM). The EDM probably has camel case as its convention. `Widget` will pick up that convention.

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EnableLowerCamelCase();

builder.EntitySet<Widget>("Widgets");

_edmModel = builder.GetEdmModel();
```

Here is a [sample OData fork of the odata/webapi repository](https://github.com/shaunluttin/WebApi/commit/c565f3397914beac39d13d802e4bd1e01791b4d1).

### Option 2

Set the MVC JSON options in `ConfigureServices`. Now JSON responses will be in camel case.

```
services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = 
            new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    });
```