# Return a string to be displayed on a View from Restful API

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, api, restful-url

I have an image of a barcode that I submit to a form. The image is posted to a restful API. The API receives the image, processes the image and throws an exception or returns a string of the barcode from the image.

Below is a snippet of my code

View -

```
<form name="somename" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
    action="/api/decoder">
    <input type="file" name="ImageToDecode" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
    <input type="submit" value="Get Barcode..." />
< /form>
```

Api -

```
public class DecodeImageController : ApiController
{
    public string Post()
    {
        var postedImage = HttpContext.Current.Request; // get the posted image

        // do some stuff in here to read the barcode from the image
        if (!could read image)
        {
            return barcode.ToString();
        }

        // barcode could not be found
        throw new Exception("Barcode could not be read");   
    }   // end post method
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2013 MVC project. The API and the View are both in separate projects. This is what gets returned.

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated
>   with it. The document tree is shown below.
>
> `<string
>   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">10320972351</string>`

This works fine, but now I want to call the API and have the returned barcode to my Controller.

Any direction would be helpful.

I am continuing to work on this as ideas pop into my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @Vladmir's answer...

You can configure your API to return string in json data type, however you will need to add formatter to return json response from API. Refer this post [How do I get ASP.NET Web API to return JSON instead of XML using Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847564/how-do-i-get-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-chrome) to know how to add formatter.

After that you can use [malsup jquery plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) to post your image to API via ajax with content type "text/html" would result barcode value in json.

Comment: thanks. I managed to get the API to return a Json(string) and added the formatter in the WebApiConfig. The API now returns json rather than xml

Answer (score 0):

This response is correct. You synchronously post form and receive correct answer.

The solution - use Json to exchange data and use jquery like $.post to send asynchronous query and perform required actions in success method of $.post

Comment: Is there a way to post image via ajax? Probably he can use [malsup plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) to post image via ajax and get response in json.