# retrieve data from database into web api

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

here is my table:

> table name: data
>
> fields:
>
> - Id
> - category
> - description
> - imagePath

I'm building a webApi that returns all imagePath or by id.

**web api controller:**

```
namespace task.Controllers
{
    public class ImagesController : ApiController
    {
        DataEntry db = new DataEntry();

        public IEnumerable<datum> GetImages()
        {
            var imagePath = from m in db.data select m;
            return imagePath;
        }

        public IHttpActionResult GetImages(int id)
        {
            var imagePath = from m in db.data select m;
            var imagPath = imagePath.Where((p) => p.Id == id);

            if (imagePath == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(imagePath);
        }
    }
}
```

It's returning all fields (Id,category, description and imagePath) instead of imagePath only.and for the select by Id method it's not working also, so what is wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `imagePath`, try specifying it in the linq query like so:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetImages()
{
    var imagePath = from m in db.data select m.imagePath;
    return imagePath.ToList();
}
```

For the select by id, try this:

```
public string GetImages(int id)
{
    var imagePath = from m in db.data select m;
    var imagPath = imagePath.Where((p) => p.Id == id);

    if (imagPath == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
     return Ok(imagPath.imagePath);
}
```

Double check for typo such as `imagPath` and `imagePath` too

Comment: can I retrieve a json file instead of xml?I tried changing the webconfig.cs file like said http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847564/how-do-i-get-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-chrome but gave me a 404 error

Comment: have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/26128440/1846040 from the same link you gave