# ASP.NET Outputting both JSON and XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, xml

I have a webapp that is currently set to output text in JSON format.  I changed this by adding the following to the webapiconfig.sys for JSOn support.  Works fine.  And when I remove support, XML works fine.

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

However, I want an additional function in the controller to output items to XML as well.  Is there a way to send the header with the output to display in XML?  Should I change something in the webapiconfig?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what exactly you are asking but if your controller supports both JSON as well as XML the client (e.g. Chrome or Fiddler) can send HTTP-headers to specify what media type it wants to receive: `Accept: application/json` or `Accept: application/xml`.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Should I add the medatypeheaders for application/json to the webapiconfig?

Comment: I'm not sure. Have look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847564/how-do-i-get-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-chrome)