# Return json as default from Umbraco API Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, umbraco

As the title says I would like to return json as default instead of XML. In a normal Web API i can edit App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs and add the following line but I can't find where to edit the configuration in Umbraco.

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

I do not wan't my method to return JsonResult to achieve this.

Comment: You can set set `content-type: 'application/json'` and `accept:'application/json` to retrieve the result in json instead of xml

Comment: @Tinwor Yes I know but I would like to get json by default in my API "text/html".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at a similar solution first @sebastiaan but decided to override "ApplicationStarting" instead.

```
public class CustomApplicationEventHandler : ApplicationEventHandler
{
    protected override void ApplicationStarting(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
}
```

And the WebApiConfig class:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom global.asax.cs like so:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Web.Http;
using Umbraco.Web;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class CustomGlobal : UmbracoApplication
    {
        private void application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var formatters = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters;
            formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
        }
    }
}
```

Update your global.asax as follow then, to point to your `CustomGlobal` class

```
<%@ Application Inherits="MyCustomGlobal" Language="C#" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach is bad because it returns JSON with a `Content-Type` of `text/html`.

See the answer and comments here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13277616/3537393

A better solution is:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12487921/3537393