# How to get JSON result using ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: json

ASP.NET Web API 2, I am able to get JSON result on local machine but when I upload same project on server it returns only XML result. Please suggest any solution for this.

Comment: How does your client request the result? Do you set the correct content-type and accept header?

Comment: I have write config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(
    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/html")
);  in WebApiConfig.cs

Comment: check this [SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847564/how-do-i-get-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-chrome)

Comment: I have already use this, but its not work for me

Comment: In chrome, it shows XML result and In Internet Explorer, it shows 500 Internal Server Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing content-type to application/json