# Asp.net web api sometimes returning content type as text/plain

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am working with ASP.NET web api. I understand response depends on the `content-type` header. I am asking this question assuming client will always send `content-type as application/json`. As suggested in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847564/how-do-i-get-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-chrome), I am using following line to return `JSON` as the default response.

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html") );
```

Until now all my controllers were returning dynamic response & data was returned as JSON.

```
    [Route("employee/division")]
    [HttpPost]
    public dynamic GetEmployeeData(FilterModel filter)
    {
         //getData returns a POCO
         var data = getData();
         //This will return valid json response to client
         return data;
    }
```

Recently, I added another endpoint which is returning `HttpResponseMessage`.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("employee/update")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Update()
    {
         ...........
          //return the response
            var msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new StringContent("Info updated !!")
            };

            return msg;

    }
```

The problem is, in this case response is returned as string. Content-Type in the response header looks like this.  `"content-type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8",`

I have following questions:

1. Why am I getting different type of response when I follow different approachs?
2. Is the approach no. 1 which is working, is that the right way to return JSON response.
3. Since I wanted to set different response code, I have decided to use approach no two. Is there any downside to this approach? How can I return JSON using this approach?

Comment: Returning `HttpResponseMessage` means that You have to take care of defining the right content type. In this case, `StringContent` means just that - a plain text string, hence `content-type: text/plain`. You could [create a JsonContent class](http://www.bizcoder.com/returning-raw-json-content-from-asp-net-web-api) to represent Json content. Or use `return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Ok, "Info updated !!");`

Comment: As @qbik highlighted, when you return type `HttpResponseMessage` you are telling the framework to bypass the media formatters, as you are in control of the response.  You can craft an `HttpResponseMessage` to return whatever you like, in this case, the `content-type` for what you are returning is `text-plain`.  Have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httpcontentheaders.contenttype.aspx) on how to change that.