# Mozilla cant Parse JSON

Tags: angular, typescript, mozilla, angular2-http

My Angular2 (RC4) gets data from my WepApi using following snippet:

```
getAppointment(id: number): Observable<Event> {
    return this._http.get(this._serviceUrl + 'get/' + id)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

the this.extractData does following:

```
private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body || {};
}
```

This all works as expected in Chrome, IE, Edge, but fails in Mozilla throwing this error:

```
JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

this leads back to the @angluar2/http module static_response.d.ts.

```
/**
 * Attempts to return body as parsed `JSON` object, or raises an exception.
 */
json(): any;
```

and thus in static_response.d.js:

```
/**
 * Attempts to return body as parsed `JSON` object, or raises an exception.
 */
Response.prototype.json = function () {
    var jsonResponse;
    if (http_utils_1.isJsObject(this._body)) {
        jsonResponse = this._body;
    }
    else if (lang_1.isString(this._body)) {
        jsonResponse = lang_1.Json.parse(this._body);
    }
    return jsonResponse;
};
```

Why doesnt this work in Mozilla?
Is this a bug in @angular2/http?

Comment: Could you try and add `console.log(res.text());` at the begining of `extractData` - just to see what's in there? Possibly the first character is `<` because of a 404 from the api.

Comment: The text shows "normal" XML which indeed starts with an "<"..

Comment: I guess that's an error message from the API?

Comment: Nope:
<ArrayOfTimeLineRowDTO xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TerminPlan.WebApi.Models"><TimeLineRowDTO><color>#f59f13</color><events><EventDTO><backgroundColor>#ffff00</backgroundColor><color1>#ffff33</color1>...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also getting same issue.

But I have resolve by changing the browser config and it work.

do this (its not proper way but it will work).

Open about:config in tab of FF.
Than find Network.http.accept.default.

value =text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

new Value=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/JSON;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Comment: i think this will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847564/how-do-i-get-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-chrome

Comment: How could I ask my customers to do this? More than 300 Offices?!

Answer (score 0):

> Since this is too long for a comment, I added this as an answer - if
>   it doesn't work I'll remove it.

---

You could try and explicitly add the `Accept` header, to tell the server you expect a JSON string as response so you don't accidently get XML, like so:

```
getAppointment(id: number): Observable<Event> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this._http.get(this._serviceUrl + 'get/' + id, options)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: Did you write the API yourself?

Comment: Its a standard WebApi made with VS..
I wunder, it is only Mozilla who is complaining.. Chrome and IE consume the WebApi in the same way, and there is no problem at all....

Comment: Did you create the WepApi with the new ASP.NET Core?