# Angular 2 on Promise call in Firefox

Tags: angular, adblock

JB Nizet, thank you! The problem is not the Adblock, but Firefox browser.
I have changed the title and problem description.
What could be a reason for an error for a simple Angular 2 call in Firefox?
        return this.http.get(this.APIGetPrice + zipcode)
            .toPromise()
            .then(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);

My page with the problem:
http://www.asbuiltsolutions.com/AsbuiltQuotes.html?p=1
enter 415 and click Next Step.

There are no problems in IE and Chrome.
The screen for Chrome debug:

[image]

The debug point is in the app.services.js,
function is APIRequestService.prototype.getPrice
Next step is: APIRequestService.prototype.extractData and I have all data I need.[image]

But Firefox returns me a complicate stack trace I am not able to debug:
[image]

Can somebody help me with Firefox debug to spot the problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Doing that in Firefox descktop, with the console opened, reveals that an exception is being thrown in JSON.parse(). So it doesn't seem to be a problem with the browser, but rather with your code: the backend returns XML, and it's parsed as JSON.

Comment: My console is pristine. I don't see the JSON.parse() error. Unfortunately, cannot attach images, but the links are: primeedge.com/asbuiltsolutions1.jpg  and primeedge.com/asbuiltsolutions2.jpg   I have no complains with desktop browsers. But can you send me the screen when you see the console error?

Comment: oh, I see it in Firefox.. checking. thank you for your hint.

Comment: I posted the updates - still no clue what is going on in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Guys from github gave me a hint where I should look for the problem:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12695

"So what I can see is that FFox is sending different Accept headers (text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8) vs. */* in Chrome."

I accepted all headers in my typescript file
private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': '*/*' });
and restricted xml type in my WebApiConfig file as:
var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);

([How do I get ASP.NET Web API to return JSON instead of XML using Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847564/how-do-i-get-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-chrome))