# C# API Return string instead of XML wrapped string

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm using ApiController and I can't get the call to return anything other than XML.

```
public class GuideController : ApiController
{
    [AcceptVerbs("GET")]

    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        Item item = Item.GetTestData();
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
        return json;
    }
}
```

Ideally, I want to return JSON normally but I'd settle for returning raw strings instead of XML wrapped ones.

Comment: What is the accept header of the request?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get ASP.NET Web API to return JSON instead of XML using Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847564/how-do-i-get-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-chrome)

Comment: Also, it should not be necessary for you to serialize your object in the controller action.  Actually, it isn't even a good idea.  For one, you are taking an operation (serialization) that is best handled in a single place, higher in the pipeline, and copying it across each of your controller actions.  The second issue is that you are hamstringing content negotiation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to make sure the api only returns JSON is to remove the xml formatter from the http configuration.

You can access the formatters in the WebApiConfig class

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        //Clear current formatters
        config.Formatters.Clear();

        //Add only a json formatter
        config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());

    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Don't serialize the object in the controller. Just return the object as is. Web api will do that for you as you have attached the json formatter to the configuration.

```
public class GuideController : ApiController
{
    [AcceptVerbs("GET")]

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        Item item = Item.GetTestData();
        return Ok(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Accept header in the client. If you want to receive JSON, set

Accept: application/json

in your client. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to return JSON explicitly.

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    Item item = Item.GetTestData();       
    return Json(item);
}
```