# WebApi can't serialize Entity Framework entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on a WebApi project and I want to serialize a `List<User>` and send it back to the user. But it just returns `[{"$id":"1"}]` where `User` is an entity which was generated by Entity Framework database-first models classes.

Controller:

```
public List<User> GetAllUsers() 
{ 
   List<User> Users = Common.Framework.Persistence.PersistSvr<Business.Entity.User>
                     .GetAll().ToList(); 
  return Users; 
}
```

Here is the `User` class:

```
 public partial class User
 {
      [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
      public User()
      {
          this.ContentLikes = new HashSet<ContentLikes>();
          this.ContentPermission = new HashSet<ContentPermission>();
          this.File = new HashSet<File>();
          this.FolderPermission = new HashSet<FolderPermission>();
          this.SiteUsers = new HashSet<SiteUsers>();
          this.UserGroup = new HashSet<UserGroup>();
      }

      public long ID { get; set; }
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
      public string LastName { get; set; }
      public string Email { get; set; }
      public string UserName { get; set; }
      public string Password { get; set; }
      public Nullable<long> DiskUsed { get; set; }
      public Nullable<long> DiskUsage { get; set; }
      public Nullable<bool> Status { get; set; }

      [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
      public virtual ICollection<ContentLikes> ContentLikes { get; set; }
      [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
      public virtual ICollection<ContentPermission> ContentPermission { get; set; }
      [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
      public virtual ICollection<File> File { get; set; }
      [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
      public virtual ICollection<FolderPermission> FolderPermission { get; set; }
      [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
      public virtual ICollection<SiteUsers> SiteUsers { get; set; }
      [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
      public virtual ICollection<UserGroup> UserGroup { get; set; }
 }
```

I have added these lines of codes to WebApiConfig.cs File.

```
 var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
 json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
 config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

it just resolved double serialization. and i have my old problem. 
i will receive `$id : "1"` when i send a request to my ActionMethod.

i have learned that it's because of EntityFramework. because WebApi doesn't able to serialize an EntityFramework Entity (i think it's because of relations that exists in my Models)

so what should i do to solve it ?
I don't want to rewrite them all.

Comment: post your apicontroller method too

Comment: Looks like you are manually serialising to JSON but returning XML. Show us how you are doing this.

Comment: @RezaNoei The first thing you need to do is configure web api to return json, get rid of your double serialization too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847564/how-do-i-get-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-chrome

Comment: Here is My Controller : 
        public JsonResult<List<User>> GetAllUsers()
        {
            List<User> Users = Common.Framework.Persistence.PersistSvr<Business.Entity.User>.GetAll().ToList();
            return Json(Users);
        }

Comment: When i removed JsonResult from my Controller. i have got an error : `The 'ObjectContent 1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public IHttpActionResult GetAllUsers()
        {
            try
            {
                List<User> Users = Common.Framework.Persistence.PersistSvr<Business.Entity.User>
                                   .GetAll().ToList(); 
                return Ok(Users);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);

            }
        }
```

You will get response in users as json along with status code.

Comment: When i removed JsonResult from my Controller. i have got an error : `The 'ObjectContent 1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.`

Comment: don't remove `JsonResult` instead `<List<User>>`

Comment: When do this i will get another problem : 
`Using the generic type 'JsonResult<T>' requires 1 type arguments`

Comment: I think, the real problem is about `Entityframework` I will Explain it in an Answer.

Comment: Sorry i checked you were right. In API , it does require, anyway i have altered my solution and it will work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172016/discussion-between-sumit-raj-and-rezanoei).