# Set Response Type of api via Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have Web API which is set to return data in JSON format. I am including attribute `[ResponseType(typeof(Class_Name))]` for each `Action` method so that api documentation (swagger) will show sample response format for each api.

Due to *some reason*, I want to return XML response for one of the api. Since I have set JSON as the default response type, the attribute `[ResponseType(typeof(Class_Name))]` for that particular api is showing response in JSON format.

Is there any way, I can show XML response for that single api? Is it possible to achieve the same by settings any attributes or some quick hacks?

Comment: The link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847564/how-do-i-get-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-chrome

Comment: Also another helpful link https://andrewlock.net/formatting-response-data-as-xml-or-json-based-on-the-url-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Isn't so that if request will have header `Accept: text/html` response will be automatically serialized in xml? Unless, of course, you explicitly removed xml serialization.