# ajax call return HTML response instead of Json in asp.net after using Newtonsoft as well

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

I am binding data on dropdown index change event using ajax call using asp.net web form following my Ajax code

```
var e = document.getElementById("<%=ddlEducation.ClientID%>");
                var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
                var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
                if (value == "0") {
                    $('#dvRecords').empty();
                    alert("Please Select Education");
                    return false;
                }

                var obj = { "iEduid": value};
                var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
                //Filling Grid View  
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: 'EditProfile.aspx/BINDEducationDATA',
                    data: myJSON,
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    success: function (response) {
                        document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_lblstram").value = response.d[i].eduStream
                        document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_lbldescs").value = response.d[i].Edu_Description
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        console.log(xhr);
                        alert(status);
                        alert(error);
                    }
                });
```

above code returns the HTML response instead of JSON

my C# code

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static List<EduDesc> BINDEducationDATA(string iEduid)
    {
        List<EduDesc> details = new List<EduDesc>();
        DataTable dtManager = new DataTable();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Edu_Stream,Edu_Description from tbl_education WHERE ID='" + iEduid + "'", con);
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(dtManager);
        }

        foreach (DataRow dtrow in dtManager.Rows)
        {
            EduDesc logs = new EduDesc();
            logs.Edu_desc = (dtrow["Edu_Description"].ToString());
            logs.eduStream = dtrow["Edu_Stream"].ToString();
            details.Add(logs);
        }
        return details;
    }
```

My Class

```
public class EduDesc
{
    public string Edu_desc { get; set; }
    public string iEduid { get; set; }
    public string eduStream { get; set; }
}
```

any help will appreciated.

Comment: please post your CS code

Comment: question is updated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get ASP.NET Web API to return JSON instead of XML using Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847564/how-do-i-get-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-chrome)

Comment: its returning XML i am getting HTMl so the my question is diffrent

Answer (score 1):

You should add `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]` to your method

```
[WebMethod]
 [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
 public static List<EduDesc> BINDEducationDATA(string iEduid)
 {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Include

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

and change the script WebMethod attribute with this:

```
[WebMethod, ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false)]
```

and you CS should look like this:

```
[WebMethod, ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false)]
public static List<EduDesc> BINDEducationDATA(string iEduid)
{
    List<EduDesc> details = new List<EduDesc>();
    DataTable dtManager = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Edu_Stream,Edu_Description from tbl_education WHERE ID='" + iEduid + "'", con);
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(dtManager);
    }

    foreach (DataRow dtrow in dtManager.Rows)
    {
        EduDesc logs = new EduDesc();
        logs.Edu_desc = (dtrow["Edu_Description"].ToString());
        logs.eduStream = dtrow["Edu_Stream"].ToString();
        details.Add(logs);
    }
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(details);
}
```

Comment: no success on above code i cnt convert List object to string

Comment: Here is a snippet that converts a List object into a string:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/QB2fTm