# After upgrading IIS server to 2019, XML api &format=xml response does not work

Tags: c#, json, .net, xml, iis

I have a project written in .NET and I updated my server from IIS 2012 to IIS 2019.

Before this update, every time I asked for response from the API and wrote **&format=xml** at the end of the URL I got the response in XML instead of Json.

For example:

```
https:....../get-customer-details?customerID=127836
my response in Json

https:....../get-customer-details?customerID=127836&format=xml
my response in XML
```

So now, after the update, `&format=xml` returns an error `page can’t be found` instead of XML response like before.

What may cause the problem?

Thanks!

I tried to check IIS configuration options and didn't find anything.

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/1957#issuecomment-237031293, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847564/how-do-i-get-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-chrome, https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/1765, and https://andrewlock.net/formatting-response-data-as-xml-or-json-based-on-the-url-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Did you upgrade from HTTP to HTTPS (secure).  You may be having issues with the TLS used for a secure connection.  IIS 2012 had limited HTTPS capability with limited encryption modes using TLS 1.2. A IIS 2019 is probably using TLS 1.3 with newer certificates and more advance encryption modes.  TLS 1.3 in some cases will not work with old encryption modes.  You probably need newer certificates to get TLS 1.3 to work.

Comment: At least, you should read IIS logs to see what's the actual response status code for such requests.

Comment: Are your server configuration options the same as before? You can try to recycle the application pool and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I get the solution by add this code to my startup.cs:

```
            services.AddMvc()
                .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();

        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat
                ("xml", MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/xml"));
            options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat
                ("config", MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/xml"));
            options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat
                ("js", MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
        })
                .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

Thank you all!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).